# The UPDATE statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am working on TableA that has Column1 with dates in this format: YYYY-MM-DD and Column2 with numbers range from 1-12.
I am trying to change the date year (THE YEAR ONLY) to 2022 WHERE Column2 = 10

NOTE: I am not trying to change the months and date.
Data type is date.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Column1 = '2021'
WHERE Column2 = 10
```

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: Are you really storing your dates as a string? Thats a very bad idea... and you show a format of `YYY-...` i.e. only 3 digits for the year, thats even worse.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags. You will need to [edit] your question to (re)tag appropriately.

Comment: To be clear, given you are using datatype date then this "dates in this format: YYYY-MM-DD" is not true, because a data datatype doesn't have a user format.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would never store a date as a string - use the correct datatype i.e. `date`. Also I assume `YYY-MM-DD` is a typo and that it should read `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Then a simple string concatenation should work

```
create table TestTable (Column1 varchar(10), Column2 int);

insert into TestTable (Column1, Column2)
select '2021-12-10', 10;

update TestTable set
    Column1 = CONCAT('2022', SUBSTRING(Column1,5,6))
where Column2 = 10;

select * from TestTable;
```

Returns:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-10 | 10 |

Note: Works on both SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: Getting this error : Argument data type date is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Comment: Data type is date.

Comment: Used the other answer and getting this error: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint.

Comment: With regard to the check constraint... you need to tell us what check constraints you have on your table, we can't see your system, you need to provide enough info for us to help.

Comment: This is the complete error:
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_TableC". The conflict occurred in database "MYDATA", table "TAbleA", column 'Column1'.

Comment: Yeah but we don't know what your check constraint does, you need to add the definition.

Comment: I am a complete beginner. I do not know what you mean. I am using sql server. Please explain a little more

Comment: Your table has a check constraint which is an integrity condition which checks the data you are storing. We need to know what it is checking, you can find out by scripting your table. For stuff you don't understand I suggest using your favourite search engine to learn more.

Comment: Check constraint [Column1] >= '1930-01-01' AND [Column1] <= dateadd(year,(-18),GETDATE())

Comment: @KhAb you check constraint is saying all column1 values must be more than 18 years ago... guess you need to sort that first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing your dates as date *data type*, then you could do it mathematically as the following:

For SQL server:

```
update TableA
set Column1 = dateadd(year, -(year(Column1) - 2022), Column1)
where Column2 = 10
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZXyepoJ-)

For MySQL

```
update TableA
set Column1 = date_add(Column1, interval -(year(Column1) - 2022) year)
where Column2 = 10
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ryM9ymZ6)

Comment: Using SQL server. data type is "date". I am getting this error when I used your code: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint.

Comment: Try to run this query `exec sp_help tablea`, this will give you information describing columns and constraints. Then tell us what these constraints are.

Comment: Check constraint [Column1] >= '1930-01-01' AND [Column1] <= dateadd(year,(-18),GETDATE())

Comment: This means that the date value should be less  than 18 years from now, I.e. less than 2005 and you try to set it to 2022

Comment: Now I want to change that. Is there a code for it? Not manually. With code.

Comment: If you don't need that constraint you could drop it, `ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP CONSTRAINT con_name`

Comment: It worked thank you for answering my questions with patient..

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Column1 = '2022' + substring(Column1,6,5)
WHERE Column2 = 10
```

So it is hard replacing 2022 to the first 4 characters and appending the rest of column1 to the end